# Handling a list of objects with React hooks and MQTT

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, mqtt, immutability

I am trying to handle a list of objects in React using hooks. The objects' updates are received using MQTT.

I first tried using a library called [mqtt-react-hooks](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mqtt-react-hooks) (which sources have disappeared from Github recently). This library provides a `useSubscription` function which among others returns the latest message received on the subscribed topic.

Basically my component looked like this, my objects being nodes:

```js
function MQTTApp(props) {
   const [nodes, setNodes] = useState([]);
   const { lastMessageOnTopic } = useSubscription('node/#');
   ...
}
```

The issue with this approach is that my component is rendered **every time a message is received**. When a MQTT message is received it needs to be parsed and **does not always lead** to an update of the nodes. What I would like is that my component is **only rendered** when the **list of nodes effectively changes**.

So I tried dumping [mqtt-react-hooks](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mqtt-react-hooks) library and writing my own code. Underneath it also uses [MQTT.js](https://github.com/mqttjs/MQTT.js). It is based on [this article](https://medium.com/@jamomani/mqtt-over-websocket-in-a-react-app-35ce96cd0844).

My code now looks like that:

```js
function MQTTApp(props) {
  const [nodes, setNodes] = useState([]);

  function handleMessage(m) {
    ...
    setNodes([...nodes, newNode]);
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    const client = mqttService.getClient();
    mqttService.onMessage(client, handleMessage);
    mqttService.subscribe(client, 'node/#');
    return () => mqttService.closeConnection(client);
  }, []);
  ...
}
```

The idea is that the component creates an MQTT client and subscribes to the topic **when mounted**. The issue I have here is that the callback **always reference the initial list of nodes** (which is empty). Since I treat my list of nodes as **immutable** I always **create a copy** when I call `setNodes` and therefore `nodes` **reference changes**. So in the end I keep loosing previous nodes when an update is received.

I can't figure out a clean and simple way of handling this. Does anyone have an idea?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `useEffect` is executed once. The `nodes` in `handleMessage` function reference which is attached to the `onMessage` listener always uses the initial value of nodes(because of closure).

**So use callback approach to set state.**

```js
function MQTTApp(props) {
  const [nodes, setNodes] = useState([]);

  function handleMessage(m) {
    ...
    setNodes(prev => [...prev, newNode]); <-------- see here
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    const client = mqttService.getClient();
    mqttService.onMessage(client, handleMessage);
    mqttService.subscribe(client, 'node/#');
    return () => mqttService.closeConnection(client);
  }, []);
  ...
}
```

Comment: Indeed! Thanks for the callback approach solution. After reading your answer, I've also found articles that help understand the problem and solve it: [React Hooks with closures: useState v/s useReducer](https://medium.com/@divyabiyani26/react-hooks-with-closures-usestate-v-s-usereducer-9e0c20e81051) and [Hooks FAQ](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#is-it-safe-to-omit-functions-from-the-list-of-dependencies) (the react-hooks/exhaustive-deps warning was there for a good reason!)

Comment: I still had a problem because I had a reference to `nodes` in order to handle updating an existing `node`. I ended up using a reducer following [this article](https://adamrackis.dev/state-and-use-reducer/).